# how to integrate tinybrowser with tinymce3.4.7

Tags: tinymce

My tinyMce editor dint worked at IE9 so that i have upgraded the tinyMce to the latest version 3.4.7 and it works. But when i added the tinyBrowser plugin to the latest version then editor seems to have some issue and display the error **tinybrowser/editor-plugin.js is fail to load** and also the editor dint display and doesn't work.

So please me the solution on how to integrate tinybrowser plugin to the latest version of tinymce 3.4.7 to work at IE9 compatiability.Thanks in Advance?

Comment: seems like this plugins still does not work correctly with IE, please file a bugreport at www.tinymce.com